# Understanding the negatives of improperly implemented hashcode method

Tags: java, hashcode

I am trying to understand what issues we can face if we implement `hashCode()` method wrongly.

For example, I tried to create a sample class `HashEx` which statically returns same hash value (100) for all the instances of the class and then tried to use `HashEx` in `HashSet`/`HashMap` with different operations:

```
HashSet -> add,read,contains
HashMap -> put,get
```

So far, all the operations seem to be working good. Any thoughts on this wild idea? I am trying to understand where this wrong implementation of `hashCode()` will create issues?

```
public class HashEx {

    public int id;
    public String name;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        HashEx e1 = new HashEx();
        e1.id=1;
        e1.name="Tom";

        HashEx e2 = new HashEx();
        e2.id=2;
        e2.name="Jerry";

        // set
        HashSet<HashEx> myset = new HashSet<HashEx>();
        myset.add(e1);
        myset.add(e2);

        System.out.println("Set size : "+ myset.size());
        for(HashEx e : myset){
            System.out.println("id: " + e.id + ", name: " + e.name);
        }

        HashEx e4 = new HashEx();
        e4.id = 2;
        e4.name = "Jerry";

        System.out.println("myset.contains(e4) : " + myset.contains(e4));

        // map
        HashMap<HashEx, String> map = new HashMap<HashEx, String>();

        map.put(e1, "Tom");
        map.put(e2, "Jerry");

        System.out.println("Map size : "+ map.size());
        System.out.println(map.get(e1));
        System.out.println(map.get(e2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(((HashEx)obj).id != id)
            return false;
        if(!((HashEx)obj).name.equals(name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything will *work* properly (so long as you correctly implement `equals(Object)` in your `HashEx` class) in the sense that you won't see any incorrect behavior.

But when you get a large number of those objects in your `HashSet` (or as keys in a `HashMap`), then you will start seeing very poor performance.  The objects are put into buckets based on their `hashCode`, and all the objects in the same bucket have to be searched linearly whenever one of the collection operations is done.

So a better test to demonstrate the problem would be write a loop that just starts adding more and more objects (until the program runs out of memory or you kill it) and print out a status message every 10,000 objects.  You'll see that the add operation gets slower and slower (quadratically).

If the objects instead have a different `hashCode` then the operation will not slow down (much) at all and it'll run out of memory much faster.

Comment: Awesome, +1 for the perfect example, here are the states

With static hashcode (100), seconds taken to add every 10000 records: 0, 2, 4, 8, 13. While with hashcode of super class, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

Comment: Everything will **not** work properly. Consider two objects: `a` and `b` such that `a.equals(b) == true`, then the Set and Map contracts are only satisfied provided that `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`. In the OP that happens to be true because they all return the same value. Otherwise, if that was not the case then the interface contract would be violated.

Comment: hashcode values should be somewhat well distributed.  typically this involves using a prime number as a multiplier.  Eclipse / IntelliJ / NetBeans can generate relatively decent .hashCode and .equals methods for you, and all you have to do is to select the fields you want to include.  Also, commons-lang comes with a HashCodeBuilder class which is really helpful.  This example uses all your object's fields in the hashCode:  return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this).  Pair that with a similar call to EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals and you're golden.